# Play system sound in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, ios13

I used to be able to play system audio files using the code below. This is not working in iOS 13 for both old and new applications.

```
import AudioToolbox
import AVFoundation

...

    func tock() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category(rawValue: convertFromAVAudioSessionCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)))

            var myAlertSound: SystemSoundID = 0
            let url: URL = URL(string: "/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Tock.caf")!
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID( (url) as CFURL, &myAlertSound)
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(myAlertSound)
        } catch {
            print("Error in audio feedback")
        }
    }

    // Helper function inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
    private func convertFromAVAudioSessionCategory(_ input: AVAudioSession.Category) -> String {
        return input.rawValue
    }
```

I don't see the "Error in audio feedback" print either.

Is there a way to play simple sounds in iOS 13?

Comment: I don't see how that could could ever have worked since you are not creating the URL correctly. You need `... = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Tock.caf")`. But even then, you shouldn't be attempting to access a file outside of your app's sandbox.

Comment: It used to work :). Maybe the location of sound files in system library has changed. I searched SO but could not find any similar questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(1104))
```

The list of all system sounds is available here: https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary